# Reference Secrets Manager Parameters to Secret String

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-secrets-manager

Is there any way to reference parameters in SecretString field in Secrets Manager via CloudFormation?

The way I made the script, the !Ref parameter is a text and not a reference to the parameter.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Parameters:

  Name:
    Type: String
  myuserparameter:
    Type: String
  mypasswordparameter:
    Type: String

Resources:  
  
  SecretsManager:
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref Name
      SecretString: '{"username":"!Ref myuserparameter,"password":"Ref mypasswordparameter"}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will work:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Parameters:

  Name:
    Type: String
  myuserparameter:
    Type: String
  mypasswordparameter:
    Type: String

Resources:  
  
  SecretsManager:
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref Name
      SecretString: !Sub '{"username": "${myuserparameter}","password": "${mypasswordparameter}"}'
```

Comment: I missed one thing, I updated my answer

Comment: I ran your script in CloudFormation and it returns this error: Invalid name. Must be a valid name containing alphanumeric characters, or any of the following: -/_+=.@!

The name I put was: teste-ssm

I'm researching what it might be.

Comment: fixed... try again!